# Using Report Designer in VS2013 and getting Assembly error loading new report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to use Report Designer in VS2013 and getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version 2.0.0.0,Culture = neutrual, PublicKey Token = '31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.  The system could not find the file specified
```

Web.config has this already in it: (The redirect should handle this issue?)

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This is the main web.config.  Do I need something else?

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: When I click the link to Design a New Report off the toolbox added to the form.  The Report Wizard pops up and then the error shows up.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The popup is a binding error from ReportViewer, Bob?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Report Designer, and particularly the DataSet Designer, does not honor binding redirects in your project. The designer is probing for assemblies using devenv.exe, and therefore using the binding redirection of devenv.exe.config. Fixing the dependency chain to match what is actually present will help this issue (in my case, Unity.MVC5 binding Unity 3.0 instead of Unity 3.5).

I am reluctant to modify devenv.exe.config as it appears to be stepped on by VS on  a somewhat regular basis.